# If a value in column A of a data frame is null, write the value from column B into column A

Tags: python, pandas

I just cannot get my head around this. I have a data frame with the following values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (1,np.nan,"a"),
    (1,"a",np.nan),
    (1,np.nan,"b"),
    (1,"c","b"),
    (2,"a",np.nan),
    (2,np.nan,"b"),
    (3,"a",np.nan)], columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

That translates into

```
   A    B    C
0  1    NaN  a
1  1    a    NaN
2  1    NaN  b
3  1    c    b
4  2    a    NaN
5  2    NaN  b
6  3    a    NaN
```

What I want is that if I have a null value / empty field in "B" it should be replaced with the value from "C". Like this:

```
   A    B    C
0  1    a    a
1  1    a    NaN
2  1    b    b
3  1    c    b
4  2    a    NaN
5  2    b    b
6  3    a    NaN
```

I can of course filer for the values:

```
df.loc[df.B.isnull()]
```

but I cannot manage to assign values from the other column:

```
df.loc[df.B.isnull()] = df.C
```

I understand that I want to replace the three NaN with seven entries in column C, so it does not match. So how do I get the corresponding values over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df.B.isnull(), 'B'] = df.C
```

Output:

```
   A  B    C
0  1  a    a
1  1  a  NaN
2  1  b    b
3  1  c    b
4  2  a  NaN
5  2  b    b
6  3  a  NaN
```

#### Or as suggested in comment below you can also use:

```
df.B.where(pd.notnull, df.C, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Or: `df.B = df.B.where(df.B, df.C)`

Comment: @JonClements Thanks! I didn't know that. Would you mind if I add this answer to edit as well?

Comment: Sure - go for it

Comment: Probably even better: `df.B.where(pd.notnull, df.C, inplace=True)`

Comment: Ok, I tried both versions on my real script. The first one gives me a warning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead. Do not know how to solve it.

The second solution works like a charm, with no warning. So I will be using this one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SLglideras well the second solution was from @JonClements, thanks  @JonClements `Happy Coding`

Answer (score 1):

You can use combine_first, it also seems to be much faster

```
df.B = df.B.combine_first(df.C)
1000 loops, best of 3: 764 µs per loop

df.loc[df.B.isnull(), 'B'] = df.C
100 loops, best of 3: 1.54 ms per loop
```

You get

```
    A   B   C
0   1   a   a
1   1   a   NaN
2   1   b   b
3   1   c   b
4   2   a   NaN
5   2   b   b
6   3   a   NaN
```

Comment: Hi, I was checking this answer as well. But, at least in the script I am working with, I am getting the error:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not str` Unfortunately, I do not have time to investigate this further. But thanks a lot as well.